# post_type_link Filter - Too Few Arguments

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I am building a website for a client with an existing website and I need to set the URLs to be exactly like they are in his old website.

I have created a custom post type with a custom taxonomy for this website.

This is the code for registering the taxonomy:

```
// Args for the phone-category taxonomy
$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'ps_dev' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'ps_dev' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search categories', 'ps_dev' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All categories', 'ps_dev' ),
    'parent_item'           => __( 'Parent category', 'ps_dev' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent category:', 'ps_dev' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit category', 'ps_dev' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update category', 'ps_dev' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add new category', 'ps_dev' ),
    'new_item_name'         => __( 'New category name', 'ps_dev' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Category', 'ps_dev' )
);

// Register the taxonomy
register_taxonomy( 'phone-category', array( 'phones' ), array(
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_rest'          => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => '/phone', 'with_front' => false )
) );
```

And this is the code for registering the new custom post type:

```
// Create the phones CPT
$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Phones', 'Post Type General Name', 'ps_dev' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Phone', 'Post type Singular Name', 'ps_dev' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Phones', 'ps_dev' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Phone', 'ps_dev' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Phones', 'ps_dev' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Phone', 'ps_dev' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Phone', 'ps_dev' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'ps_dev' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Phone', 'ps_dev' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Phone', 'ps_dev' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Phone', 'ps_dev' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not Found', 'ps_dev' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'ps_dev' ),
);

$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'phones', 'ps_dev' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Phone numbers' , 'ps_dev' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'phones-category' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_ui_menu'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menu'      => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => false,
    'exclude_from_seach'    => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'show_in_rest'          => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => '/phone/%post_name%/', 'with_front' => false )
);

register_post_type( 'phones', $args );
```

As can be seen in the code above, the URL structure I need for the CPT is `/phone/%post_name%/` and the URL structure I need for the taxonomy is `/phone/%taxonomy_title%/`

So for example, if there is a `phone` item called `test`, its URL should be `/phone/test/`.
If we have a `phone-category` taxonomy called `taxonomy_test`, its URL should be `/phone/taxonomy_test`.

The taxonomy URL works well.
The issue is with the CPT's URL.

I am trying to use this code:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'phone_custom_permalink' );
function phone_custom_permalink( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'phones' ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    return str_replace('/%post_name%/', $post->post_name, $post_link );
}
```

But when I open the `phones` post's edit page, it throws an error:

```
 phone_custom_permalink(), 1 passed in D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\theindex\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 309 and exactly 2 expected in D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\theindex\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\post-types\phones.php:90 Stack trace: #0 D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\theindex\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(309): phone_custom_permalink('http://theindex...') #1 D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\theindex\wp-includes\plugin.php(189): WP_Hook->apply_filters('http://theindex...', Array) #2 D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\theindex\wp-includes\link-template.php(370): apply_filters('post_type_link', 'http://theindex...', Object(WP_Post), false, false) #3 D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\theindex\wp-includes\link-template.php(201): get_post_permalink(Object(WP_Post), false, false) #4 D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\theindex\wp-includes\rest-api\endpoints\class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php(1776): get_permalink(Object(WP_Post)) #5 D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\theindex\wp-includes\rest-a in D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\theindex\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\post-types\phones.php on line 90
```

I tried to follow some guides but in each one, I am still getting this error.
When I change it to this:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'phone_custom_permalink' );
function phone_custom_permalink( $post_link, $post=0 ) { // The change is here
    if ( $post->post_type != 'phones' ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    return str_replace('/%post_name%/', $post->post_name, $post_link );
}
```

I am not getting the error, but it just does not work (the URL in the post edit page is with `/&post_name%/`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to do :

```php
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'phone_custom_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

To tell the hook that you are passing it 2 arguments.

Comment: I added the `, 10, 2 ` and I am not getting an error now but when I try to load the page it gives me a 404 even after flushing permalinks

Comment: Certainly, this problem comes from the configuration of the CPT.

Comment: Do you have an idea why though?

Comment: Try this `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'phone','with_front' => false)`. Without adding your hook.

Comment: I understand now why it is not working. I am trying to use the same slug for both the CPT item and its taxonomy and apparently, it conflicts. When I change the slug of either one of them, it works. The thing is, I need them both to have the same slug. Do you know how to implement this or have a direction to throw me at?

Comment: Maybe this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959851/how-do-i-use-the-same-slugs-for-custom-post-types-and-taxonomies-in-wordpress

Comment: I just saw it too and tried it but it does work the way I need it to